# Webserver communication security in android

Tags: java, android, security, webserver

So I'm trying to make a game for android. It's based on Gazillionaire a game i played when i was a little kid. The game is played with 6 players and it's turn based (so no realtime requirements here). I figured it would be best if i store the data from one turn in a database and have a web application (PHP) that the android client can communicate with. I'm using the buildin apache DefaultHttpClient to communicate with the webserver. I use post variable to give commands like

```
$_POST['action'] = 'login';
$_POST['username'] = 'username';
$_POST['password'] = long sha256 hash
$_POST['challenge'] = ????; //also thinking about using challenges
```

This all works fine but. How do I secure my application. I don't want the webserver to be exploided so users can make their own clients.

Do I have to secure my application or am I fine? Anyone have any experience with this type of application?

Answer (score 1):

Also use SSL encryption to communicate with your server! So all your traffic gets encrypted and cannot be read by a man in the middle.

Good article about SSL and custom certificates is here: [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872)